# grep and nawk order difference

Tags: awk, grep, solaris, disk-usage

[image]

Could you explain why grep->nawk doesn't work in this situation?

Comment: It’s a straightforward explanation, but could I bother you to transcribe the two commands from the image?

Comment: https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4086/117549

Comment: @JeffSchaller's answer is correct....but you don't need both `grep` and `nawk` here.   `df -h | nawk '$6 ~ /^\/$/ {print $6}'` is all that's needed.  or `$6 == "/"`. Whenever find yourself piping `grep` into `awk` you should think to yourself "I don't need to do that, awk can do everything that grep can and a lot more".

Comment: Or just `df -h /`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The order matters here because of the pattern you used for `grep`. The pattern says: at the beginning of the line, have a forward slash, followed by the end of the line.

The first command runs `awk` ahead of the `grep`; it prints the mount points. The only mount point that matches the `grep` is `/`.

The second command runs `grep` first, and since none of the lines from `df` match the pattern, nothing is printed.

Comment: Thank you kind sir. So Grep only looks at $1 field in this situation?

Comment: @Lunartist `grep` is told to look at the beginning of its input line since the regular expression is anchored (with `^`) at the beginning of the line.